# Why map.off doesnt work correctly mapboxGL JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

i create eventListener with

> `map.on('mousemove', (event) => handlerValues(event))`

i must use event in `handlerValues`, but when i use

> `map.off('mousemove', (event) => handlerValues(event))`
> it doesn't work

i wrapped `handlerValues` in `useCallback`, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

i find solution, that's crutch but you can use .filter on map._listeners.mousemove, and remove listener which you want delete

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).